# Axes plot of a 3D cartesian coordinate system

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, coordinate-systems

How would you plot the axes of a 3D *orthonormal* cartesian coordinate system?

Assuming the axes are labeled $x, y, z$ (see figure below) and that if you look at the $yz$-plane you see a uniform grid (squares), what should be the length of the unit vector of axis $x$ you plot. Is there any specifics or standards for the angle between axes $x$ and $y$ (in the plot of course). Should it be 135 degrees for example?

[image]

Comment: Yes, without being a standard value, it's usual to take this angle.

Comment: @JeanMarie Okay. What about the length? My problem is that according to the length chosen for plotting, the shape of objects may change. For example, a cube may or may not look as a cube depending on the length we choose for the $x$ unit vector. On the other hand, as the $x$-axis is tilted we expect the dimension of the cube on this axis to change according to the angle (view). Nonetheless, I think that fixing it to 1 as the other axes ($y$ and $z$) would be wrong...

Comment: I misread your question. Take $\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \approx 0.707$ for your "??"

Comment: @JeanMarie This was my initial guess but apparently not everybody does that.

Comment: I realize that the answer is less evident than I thought at first. I am not longer sure about the square root of 2 divided by 2... It may depend on the "height of the observer's eye" you want to give... I must think about it...

Comment: @JeanMarie After some search, it appears that this axes' configuration corresponds to a known projection called "oblique projection" where different variants exist (with different defined angles and different scaling factors for the equivalent $x$-axis such as cavalier and cabinet $45^\circ$) see [here](http://www.tilemapeditor.com/glossary/oblique-projection/).

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @JeanMarie You're very welcome :-)

Comment: Relevent post: http://www.significant-bits.com/a-laymans-guide-to-projection-in-videogames/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use graphing paper, or any similar method with a regular square base grid, the three I prefer are

[image: three]

because of the ease in both drawing and perception; each one of the above shows a typical unit cube drawn in $(0,0,0)-(1,1,1)$.

The center one has been particularly common in computer games, and is close to military projection. The vertical Z axis units in military projection match the X and Y axis units (as measured in the projection), but in the above image, the Z axis units projected length are only $1:\sqrt{2}$ or about 70% of the X and Y axis units projected length.

The left and right projections are trimetric, with Z axis units $\sqrt{4/5}$ or about 89% of the X and Y axis units. It turns out that this difference is not as perceptible. The angles in the left and right trimetric projections, above, are 90° (top), 116.565°, and 153.435°.

If $x$ increases down left, $y$ down right, $z$ up, with the dotted-line vertex as the origin, and projected $x^{,}$ right and $y^{,}$ down, then
$$\begin{cases} x^{,} = y - 2 x \\
y^{,} = 2 z - x - 2 y \end{cases}$$
for the leftmost projection;
$$\begin{cases} x^{,} = y - x \\
y^{,} = z - x - y \end{cases}$$
for the center projection; and
$$\begin{cases} x^{,} = 2 y - x \\
y^{,} = 2 z - 2 x - y \end{cases}$$
for the rightmost projection.

Comment: Do you know what is commonly used to graph math functions of two variables $f(x,y)$ ($f$ here is the $z$ variable)? And how should one choose one of the projections? Are there any specific criteria?

Comment: @MedNait: Because the main reason to use a graph is to convey information, the only criteria that really matters is which projection provides the most illustrative, easy to understand, and least confusing graph. I personally use gnuplot (`splot f(x,y)`) very often, which lets me rotate the graph in real time, with various commands specifying the x, y, z ranges and options (like contour curves). Without computer tools, I'd start with pure 2D contour plots, similar to topographic maps; then compare, in my mind, how it might look in the "easy" projections.

Comment: Fair enough thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**This is an answer to a self-asked question, so very comments are welcome to enrich and discuss the content**.

It turns out that this view of the Cartesian coordinate system corresponds to the so-called "[Oblique projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_projection)" of the 3D objects we want to represent. This projection has the advantage of representing one side (here the projection into the $yz$-plane) of the considered 3D object with its true, non distorted, form (scaled of course). Even though this type of projection is not the most realistic (see [perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_(graphical))) it seems it is the easiest for representing 3D objects in 2D.

Oblique projections are characterized by two parameters: the angle $\theta$ at which we draw the side of the 3D object and the scaling factor (aka foreshortening factor) $s$, which is the ratio between the plotted length and the real length of the 3D object along the viewing direction. The choices of $\theta$ and $s$ may be arbitrary and the projection still would be oblique. Nonetheless, some specific values have been used until their use spread. I cite cavalier and cabinet (with its variants) projections. Bellow, I give two examples of such projections. What it represented is a cube with side $a$.

### Cavalier oblique projection

Characterized specifically by a scaling factor $s=1$ and an angle $\theta= 45^\circ$.

[image: Cavalier]

### Cabinet $45^\circ$ oblique projection

Characterized by a scaling factor $s=\frac{1}{2}$ and angle $\theta= 45^\circ$. Other Cabinet projections exist also (see [here](http://www.tilemapeditor.com/glossary/oblique-projection/)).

[image]

Comment: Because of games people are more familiar with [Isometric, Diametric & Trimetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_graphics_in_video_games_and_pixel_art) projections.